# Proper way to update collection view datasource for multiple call swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, fetch, collectionview, performbatchupdates

I have a collection view and I am loading 20 cells in every call (*Fetching*) from firebase in it. So I have two sections where the first section is the count number of my source array and the second section is just showing the loading cell when a `bool` value `fetch more` is true.

This is the collection view code:

```
extension ProductViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return self.objectArray.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            return fetchingMore ? 1 : 0
        }
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        var minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt: CGFloat
        if section == 0 {
            minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt = -50
        } else {
            minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt = 0
        }
        return minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: productCollectionView.bounds.width, height: CommonService.heightForRowAtIndexPathForiPhones(cellType: .itemCell))
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: productCollectionView.bounds.width, height: 70)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemAlbumCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemAlbumCollectionViewCell
            cell.setUpCell(product: objectArray[indexPath.row]!)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LoadingCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCollectionViewCell
            cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let productCategoryViewController = Storyboards.ProductCategoryVC.controller as! ProductCategoryViewController
        productCategoryViewController.products = objectArray[indexPath.row]!
        pushViewController(T: productCategoryViewController)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            guard let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "StreachyCollectionHeaderReusableView", for: indexPath) as? StreachyCollectionHeaderReusableView else { fatalError("Invalid view type") }
            return headerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }
    }
}
```

And this the function which is called for fetching data:

```
func pagination(forDivisionCollection: String) {
    fetchProduct(forDivisionCollection: forDivisionCollection, completion: { newData in
        self.productCollectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1))
        self.objectArray.append(contentsOf: newData)
        self.endReached = newData.count == 0
        self.fetchingMore = false

        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.productCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

**And it is working perfectly.**

Now I have added a top menu section with a couple of options.

[image]

If a user taps on that section the function `func pagination(forDivisionCollection: String)` will be called with a parameter and it will filter data source with that parameter and populate data source according to the top menu option like this:

```
func pagination(isForNewDivision: Bool, forDivisionCollection: String) {
    self.fetchingMore = true
        if isForNewDivision == true {
            self.objectArray.removeAll()
        }
    fetchProduct(forDivisionCollection: forDivisionCollection, completion: { newData in
        self.productCollectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1))
        self.objectArray.append(contentsOf: newData)
        self.endReached = newData.count == 0
        self.fetchingMore = false

        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.productCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

But I am getting `'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.` warning on Xcode when running it in the simulator and it is getting crashed on the physical device. I have researched a bit and come up with the solution of using `performBatchUpdates` but none of them are working. So my question is in this kind of situation what would be the perfect way to fetch data and load in collection view? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you needing to deploy to less than ios13 ? Investigate NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource. Your approach of calling both reloadSections and reloadData is problematic and will be a source of never ending issues for a multi section collection. What you’re  doing is possible but is brittle even when done well. See also https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/220

Comment: @WarrenBurton Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Yes, my deployment target is below iOS 13. Ok, I am looking into it.

Comment: You can use - https://github.com/onmyway133/DeepDiff to grab the changes between your objects and then perform batch updates on it. It has an example project on there.

Comment: Thanks for the link. OK, I am looking into it.